# How to convert simple feature collections of geometry type POLYHEDRALSURFACE to MULTIPOLYGON?

Tags: gdal, r, sf

Messing around with CityGML data in order to obtain building footprints, I found a solution using `ogr2ogr` to extract individual layers to "more common" vector data formats some time ago in [a blog post](https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/svitalis/citygml/gdal/2017/07/24/messing-around-with-citygml-on-gdal-2.2.html) and was also able to reproduce this using OSGeo4W Shell (GDAL 3.8.4).

Now I would like to be able to perform this using R, which seems to be a little bit more complicated, since the "GMLAS" driver does not seem to be shipped with the GDAL instance `{sf}` is using on Windows.

As we can see, the GML driver is used per default and does only recognize one single layer.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.7.2, PROJ 9.3.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# get some data
f <- "LoD1_32_280_5657_1_NW.gml"

utils::download.file(paste0("https://www.opengeodata.nrw.de/produkte/geobasis/3dg/lod1_gml/lod1_gml/", f),
                     f)

sf::gdal_utils(util = "ogrinfo", source = f)
#> INFO: Open of `LoD1_32_280_5657_1_NW.gml'
#>       using driver `GML' successful.
#> Metadata:
#>   NAME=LoD1_32_280_5657_1_NW
#> 1: Building (3D PolyhedralSurface)

"GMLAS" %in% sf::st_drivers()$name
#> FALSE
```

Just to provide a comparison, these layers are actually available when inspecting via GMLAS:

```
ogrinfo GMLAS:LoD1_32_280_5657_1_NW.gml
INFO: Open of `GMLAS:LoD1_32_280_5657_1_NW.gml'
      using driver `GMLAS' successful.
1: buildingpart (PolyhedralSurface, Multi Curve)
2: buildingpart_metadataproperty (None)
3: buildingpart_name (None)
4: building (PolyhedralSurface, Multi Curve)
5: building_metadataproperty (None)
[...]
145: locality_largemailuser_buildingname_buildingname (None)
146: locality_postalroute_addressline_addressline (None)
147: locality_dependentlocality_addressline_addressline (None)
148: localit_dependelocalit_dependelocalitname_dependelocalitname (None)
149: administrativearea_addressline_addressline (None)
150: administratiarea_subadministratiarea_addressline_addressline (None)
```

However, the layer "Building" using GML driver does not look that bad at first glance in QGIS (also only detecting one layer, just like in R), so I would like to give it a try.

Data is imported without visible errors, but it seems like many `sf::st_*()` functions cannot be applied on this type of geometry (for good reasons, I guess).

```r
x <- sf::st_read(f)
#> Reading layer `Building' from data source 
#>   `LoD1_32_280_5657_1_NW.gml' 
#>   using driver `GML'
#> Simple feature collection with 81 features and 22 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYHEDRALSURFACE
#> Dimension:     XYZ
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 280851.8 ymin: 5657120 xmax: 281004.9 ymax: 5657728
#> z_range:       zmin: 35.74 zmax: 47.632
#> Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N

sf::st_area(x)
#> Warning in CPL_area(x): GDAL Error 6: SFCGAL support not enabled.
#> Units: [m^2]
#>  [1] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
#> [26] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
#> [51] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
#> [76] -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

plot(x[, "measuredHeight_uom_"])
#> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log): 'x' is a list, but does not have any 'x' and 'y' components
```

Since there does not seem to exist lots of information about POLYHEDRALSURFACE geometry in the docs, my naive approach was to make use of `sf::st_cast()`, obviously failing:

```r
sf::st_cast(x, "MULTIPOLYGON")
#> Error in scan(text = lst[[length(lst)]], quiet = TRUE): scan() expected 'a real', got 'ParseException:'
#> Error in (function (msg) : ParseException: Unknown WKB type 15
```

What did work (despite 35 warnings) in a presumably messy way, was to write `x` temporarily to disk in SHP format and re-import, but I guess there must be some sophisticated way not dropping 8 of the columns - and who knows what I did to geometry without even noticing.

```r
sf::st_write(x, "lod1_test_v1.shp")
#> Warning in abbreviate_shapefile_names(obj): Field names abbreviated for ESRI
#> Shapefile driver
#> Error in clean_columns(as.data.frame(obj), factorsAsCharacter): list columns are only allowed with raw vector contents

sf::gdal_utils(util = "vectortranslate", 
               source = f, 
               destination = "lod1_test_v2.shp", 
               options = c("-f", "ESRI Shapefile"))
#> [...]
#> Warning in CPL_gdalvectortranslate(source, destination, options, oo, doo, :
#> GDAL Message 1: The output driver does not natively support StringList type for
#> field consistsOfBuildingPart|BuildingPart|creationDate. Misconversion can
#> happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
#> [...]

y <- sf::st_read("lod1_test_v2.shp")
y
#> Reading layer `lod1_test_v2' from data source 
#>   `lod1_test_v2.shp' 
#>   using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 81 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XYZ
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 280851.8 ymin: 5657120 xmax: 281004.9 ymax: 5657728
#> z_range:       zmin: 35.74 zmax: 47.632
#> Projected CRS: ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N

sf::st_area(y) |> round(1)
#> Units: [m^2]
#>  [1]   7.5  36.3  24.1  35.1  85.8  38.8  27.6 128.7  29.9 183.1 170.1  35.7
#> [13]  57.4  12.2  69.6  58.9  36.0  58.9  31.6 133.0 140.6  79.2  39.1 110.0
#> [25]  21.9  15.5 114.3  53.8  59.8 118.0 133.2  20.8  52.4  28.5  47.1 437.6
#> [37] 151.2 169.9  43.4  39.3  41.9  30.8  77.0  78.3  11.9  56.5  72.0 225.8
#> [49]  50.2  48.5  41.0  23.1  43.5 239.3  69.8  25.5 109.6   2.6  85.0  44.7
#> [61] 171.8  53.4  55.4  62.2  10.4  53.3  53.7   3.6  32.9  29.3 135.5  90.4
#> [73]  38.4  75.5 118.3  39.7  63.6  74.1  26.2 253.0 132.9

plot(y[, "measuredHe"])
```